# how to add new category to foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I see that there is no very useful category in the foursquare category list provided by API.
This category is "Car services".

And what's more important for me in RU locale is that it should be "Автосервис" or "Станция технического обслуживания авто".

Now many venues are marked with the wrong category because of the absence of these categories.
For example, car service venues are marked as "Automotive Shops" or in Russian "Магазин автотоваров". This is completely the wrong meaning.

So the question is how can I request for the addition of a new category?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to add venue categories via the Foursquare API, but please feel free to reach out to Foursquare support directly with your feedback: http://support.foursquare.com/requests/new